# Java desktop app fails to run if max heap size set to >1G on Windows 7 64-bit despite having latest 64-bit Jre

Tags: java, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run [this Java desktop application](http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/downloads.jsp) on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with 32G RAM. It runs fine when the jnlp file sets: max-heap-size="1024m", but if the max heap size is increased to 2048 or 4096 the Java start animation runs for a few seconds and a new process is visible in task manager then it just stops with no error message.

[image]

I have tried updating my Jre to the latest 64-bit version. "java -version" gives:
[image]

I've also configured the Java start parameters to -Xmx4096m, but this does not fix it:
[image]

Very grateful for any suggestions - I run analyses using this tool and the extra RAM could save me a great deal of time.

Comment: Try enabling the Java console.  You may see what exception the application is encountering.  You can enable the console in the Java control panel, fifth tab.  (That tab has the title "Advanced" in the English version.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying this, but the console doesn't appear when using either version with max heap size set >1G (it does appear for 1G max heap size).

Comment: Search for javacpl.exe (the program behind your screenshot), maybe the version referenced in the windows control panel is not the version for your 64-bit java.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but didn't come up with any other versions of javacpl.exe. However, I did notice that I had the 32-bit Jre installed - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed this myself, though it turned out to be something I should have checked properly from the beginning. My system had a second Jre installed - the 32-bit version. After uninstalling this, the Java app was able to load with a higher max heap size.